# “@angular/router”: “3.0.0-beta.2”: routerLink to a (primary and auxiliary) router-outlet not resolving

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to populate a primary `<router-outlet>` and an auxiliary `<router-outlet>` from a `[routerLink]` - when I just populate the primary `<router-outlet>` it works, and when I just populate the auxiliary `<router-outlet>` is also works, but I try to populate both simultaneously it isn't able to resolve one or both of the routes.

App Routes

```
const APP_ROUTES:RouterConfig = [
    {path:'', pathMatch:'full', component:EmptyComponent},
    {path:'dog', pathMatch:'prefix', component:DogComponent},
    {path:'bird', pathMatch:'prefix', outlet:'under', component:BirdComponent}
];
```

App Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h3>Auxiliary Router Outlets</h3>
  <hr>
  <ul>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['']">Clear</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['dog']">Over Dog</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['under:bird']">Under Bird</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['dog(under:/bird)']">Over Dog & Under Bird</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <hr>
  <router-outlet name='under'></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Here's the Plunker that shows how I've got everything set up:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PI7qaWLVwG6CYOwm7iJC?p=preview

I've studied Victor Savkin's blog post about the Angular2 3.0.0 router:

http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router

but the post is closed for comments...

I have a post on AngularJS Google Groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/mAKbiQgxibg

And the official documentation "teases" the subject:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html